# Correct adjective for "Cannot be ordered according to (criterion) A"

Tags: adjectives

For example, talking of a criterion to order pebbles named the Zwet criterion:

> Despite its strengths, it should be noted that most pebbles cannot be ordered according to the
>   Zwet criterion.

Because the "Zwet criterion" is used many times in the surrounding text, I would have written:

> Despite its strength, it should be noted that most types of pebbles are not Zwet ordanable

that is, if "ordanable" was an adjective. My question is, what is the correct adjective to use in place of "ordanable".

Comment: I would suggest *orderable* instead.

Comment: @DanBron: looks like what I'm looking for. Mind putting it as an answer?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.2621.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use *orderable* (ugly), and I would not bother with *Zwet criterion* (at least once it has been introduced). And I would drop *it should be noted* (just note it; don't tell the reader that it should be noted).

I would just say this:

- *Despite its strengths, most pebbles cannot be Zwet ordered.*

Answer (score 3):

Rather than *ordanable*, I'd recommend ***orderable***.

Per [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/orderable):

> **orderable**:
>
> - ***adj***. That may be ordered (obtained by placing an order).
> - ***adj***. That may be ordered (put in sequence).

It's the second sense you're looking for, here.